# Why is my code for a single fql query not working anymore?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have the following code:

```
     <?php

      require '../src/facebook.php';

     // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret). 

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'app_id',
    'secret' => 'app_secret'
    ));
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    $fql = "select user_id, object_id, object_type from like where user_id=me()";
    $result = $facebook->api(array(
         'method'       => 'fql.query',
         'access_token' => $access_token, //tried either with/without this
         'query'        => $fql,
      ));
    print_r($result);
?>
```

It used to work perfectly but now it is just returning an empty array() Can this be solved? or is there any other code that could work better?
note: I have all the access tokens necessary, I tried small changes in the code like quotations, spaces...
please help

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It should work !! There was an issue in the like table back in 2013 which is resolved.

One of the issue not getting data is that your application does not ask for **read_stream**

So in the login part you may need to pass the scope **read_stream**

You can check here.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Generate a new access token by adding extended permission **read_stream**

And then run your FQL.

I just tested your FQL in my app which ask for **read_stream** and it works pretty well I get the data.

Comment: hi Abhik, this is not the problem... I have read_steam enabled. The code was working perfectly yesterday but wouldn't work today.

Comment: hmm do u get any exceptions in the graph api or just getting blank array ?

Comment: I am getting a blank array

Comment: hmm not sure what it is but there is nothing wrong in ur code and as I said it works well, I have tested it. May be u can see error log if it tells something which is obvious. Also you can try running other api calls like /me and see if they are working.

Comment: alright thx a lot Abhik, I hope it will not turn out to be something stupid :P